# Is the pi-zero capable enough to play video?

Tags: video, pi-zero

The project would be a turnkey video player: plug it in to the hdmi display and power, and it plays a prepared video list in a loop.  No user controls or anything; brute stupid to use in the field.

Is the pi-zero fast enough and/or its GPU capble enough to play full-HD video?  Note that it’s not some arbitrary files but fixed prepared files, so I could be sure to use a suitable codec and compression options.

Answer (score 12):

Yes. As far as I can remember, pretty much every Pi I've ever tried to play 1920x1080 video on has worked, up to and including the very first generation boards. You can see a brief sample of the Zero playing back 1080 resolution footage from Big Buck Bunny using Kodi on the [KordKutters Youtube channel](https://youtu.be/Q8GZr2fyUY0?t=7m45s). Looks fine to me, although the presenter notes a little slowdown during add-on updates - you shouldn't have this issue if you're only playing back footage.

If your end goal is just 'build a Pi that plays looped video' it may be worth a look at the ready-made image provided by [MP4Museum](http://mp4museum.org/). It doesn't do much else, but it apparently does that well.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is. And it's also worth mentioning `omxplayer`, a neat command line video player with lots of options, see this [elinux post](http://elinux.org/Omxplayer) and this [RPi documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/video/).

Install it with 
`sudo apt-get install -y omxplayer`

If you want to compile `omxplayer` from source, follow this [readme](https://github.com/huceke/omxplayer) on github.

Comment: While this might be useful information and could work as a comment (or as an answer to a different question), it does not answer the question asked here, which is "Is the pi-zero capable enough to play video?"

Comment: A "yes it is" will fix that.

Comment: `omxplayer` is deprecated since Jul 2020: https://github.com/popcornmix/omxplayer